# Why is my sprite getting stretched during look_at function?

Tags: godot

When my sprite is facing up/down it gets warped (gets longer) and when it is facing left/right it looks normal. Could this potentially coming from my sprite rotation? I'm using a `.png` image for my sprite.

[image]
[image]

Below is my code:

`Player.gs`

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(BUTTON_LEFT):
        destination = get_global_mouse_position()
        # if position.distance_to(destination) > 100:
        speed += acceleration * delta
        if speed > max_speed:
            speed = max_speed
        velocity = position.direction_to(destination) * speed
        # move_direction = rad2deg(destination.angle_to_point(position))
        $Sprite.look_at(destination)
        
        
    else:
        speed = 0
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, 0, 0.025)
    velocity.y = lerp(velocity.y, 0, 0.025)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out having the method `$Sprite.look_at(destination)` was causing my issue. What I should be doing is only `look_at(destination)`. This solved my issue.